# Materialize tabs not scrolling

Tags: tabs, materialize

I am using Materialize v0.98.0 (local copy) and have the following code. I've message around with CSS settings in Chrome console, but can't seem to figure it out.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../_css/materialize.css"  media="screen,projection,print"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../_js/materialize.js"></script>

#roll_tabs {
    webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.12),0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
        <ul class="tabs" id="roll_tabs">
            <li class="tab col"><a href="#EX-33-04-01">EX-33-04-01</a></li>
            <li class="tab col"><a href="#EX-33-05">EX-33-05</a></li>
            <li class="tab col"><a href="#EX-33-06">EX-33-06</a></li>
            <li class="tab col"><a href="#EX-33-07">EX-33-07</a></li>
            <li class="tab col"><a href="#FS-040">FS-040</a></li>
            <li class="tab col"><a href="#EX-33-01" class="">EX-33-01</a></li>
            <li class="tab col"><a href="#CL-400">CL-400</a></li>
            <li class="tab col"><a href="#EX-34-01">EX-34-01</a></li>
            <li class="tab col"><a href="#FS-PA-01-9" class="">FS-PA-01-9</a></li>
            <li class="tab col"><a href="#FS-PA-02-17">FS-PA-02-17</a></li>
            <li class="tab col"><a href="#EX-33-02">EX-33-02</a></li>
            <li class="tab col"><a href="#FS-SOL-01">FS-SOL-01</a></li>
            <li class="tab col"><a href="#Ex-33-03">Ex-33-03</a></li>
            <li class="tab col"><a href="#EX-34-02" class="active">EX-34-02</a></li>
            <li class="tab col"><a href="#EX-33-04-02" class="">EX-33-04-02</a></li>              
        </ul>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tabs').tabs({
        onShow: function(event, ui) {
        formID = $('ul.tabs li a.active').html();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On using `swipeable : true` you can achieve scrolling(to be more precise **swiping** not **scrolling**). You've used a `class` of `col`, this doesn't work like that, you need to give the size of the grid too.

[CodePen Demo of Tabs Swiping](https://codepen.io/germavinsmoke/pen/VBaOYg)

And Use the newest versions of materialize cdnjs/minified scripts -

```
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The issue I'm having is that I have a large number of tabs, and they don't fit within the outer div. Materialize is supposed to automatically make the tabs scrollable (not swipeable) so that you can view the hidden tabs. Instead, it's just shifting them to the next line and hiding them.